# React.js - How to set a default value for input date type

Tags: reactjs

I would like to set the default date to be 3 days from todays date when the date picker opens up on the browser. How can I achieve that?

```
<input id="dateRequired" type="date" name="dateRequired" />
```

Answer (score 46):

You need to convert the date to iso string and get first 10 characters.
e.g.

```html
var curr = new Date();
curr.setDate(curr.getDate() + 3);
var date = curr.toISOString().substring(0,10);
<input id="dateRequired" type="date" name="dateRequired" defaultValue={date} />
```

Reference [toISOString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) method.
Also you can see the result [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/18m28o0y03)

Answer (score 19):

You need set the defaultValue attribute of the date input as `yyyy-mm-dd` like so:

```
const today = new Date();
const numberOfDaysToAdd = 3;
const date = today.setDate(today.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd); 
const defaultValue = new Date(date).toISOString().split('T')[0] // yyyy-mm-dd

<input id="dateRequired" type="date" name="dateRequired" defaultValue={defaultValue} />
```

Here is a working example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-christian-22czv?file=/src/App.js:326-346

#### 2022 Answer

You can use [toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) with a locale to get the date string in `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const date = new Date();
    const futureDate = date.getDate() + 3;
    date.setDate(futureDate);
    const defaultValue = date.toLocaleDateString('en-CA');

    return (
      <input id="dateRequired" type="date" name="dateRequired" defaultValue={defaultValue} />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.body
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying.. but the page does not render when i add defaultValue to the input field.

Comment: It says date is not defined.

Comment: Can you update your original post with your full component?

Comment: in my case was not working because i was passing a value as well: `<input id="dateRequired" value ={date} type="date" name="dateRequired" defaultValue={date} />`, removed value and it worked

Comment: This answer does not work!

Answer (score 3):

## 2022 Answer

#### using `jsx`

```
import { useState } from 'react'

const Component = () => {
    
    let defaultDate = new Date()
    defaultDate.setDate(defaultDate.getDate() + 3)

    const [date, setDate] = useState(defaultDate)

    const onSetDate = (event) => {
        setDate(new Date(event.target.value))
    }

    return (
        <>
            <p>date: {date.toString()}</p>
            <p>date: {date.toLocaleDateString('en-CA')}</p>
            <input type="date" value={date.toLocaleDateString('en-CA')} onChange={onSetDate} />
        </>
    )
}

export default Component
```

#### using `tsx`

```
import { useState } from "react"

const Component = (): JSX.Element => {
    
    let defaultDate = new Date()
    defaultDate.setDate(defaultDate.getDate() + 3)

    const [date, setDate] = useState<Date>(defaultDate)

    const onSetDate = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
        setDate(new Date(event.target.value))
    }

    return (
        <>
            <p>date: {date.toString()}</p>
            <p>date: {date.toLocaleDateString('en-CA')}</p>
            <input type="date" value={date.toLocaleDateString('en-CA')} onChange={onSetDate} />
        </>
    )
}

export default Component
```

Comment: This code breaks if someone tries to type in the date because invariably the date is temporarily in invalid date states and the call to toLocalDateString() fails...

Answer (score 3):

Create a helper function that returns the correct format of the `<input type="date" />` which is `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Let's define a function:

```js
const getCurrentDateInput = () => {

  const dateObj = new Date();

  // get the month in this format of 04, the same for months
  const month = ("0" + (dateObj.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
  const day = ("0" + dateObj.getDate()).slice(-2);
  const year = dateObj.getFullYear();

  const shortDate = `${year}-${month}-${day}`;

  return shortDate;
};
```

Then go back to the input tag and type the following :

```
<input type="date" defaultValue={getCurrentDateInput()}  />
```

Comment: should I do this in  useEffect or just a regular JS function?

Comment: no, you just put in a regular function or separate file, and call it whenever u need it.

Answer (score 0):

**Declare a state :-**

```
this.state={ 
   recentDate:new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10)
}
```

**Declare a function by means of which you can also be able select different dates.**

```
selectedDate(e){    
     this.setState({recentDate:e.target.value})    
}
```

**Call the state into value attribute and selectedDate function in onChange prop.**

```
<input 
    type="date" 
    value={this.state.rencentDate} 
    onChange={this.selectedDate} 
 />
```