# How to set today date as default for Material UI datepicker

Tags: reactjs, date, material-ui

In my react app, I am using Material UI datepicker.
Unfortunately I am not able to set today's date as default date.
here is my code:

```
<TextField 
          id="dateTimeFrom"                                        
          type="date"
          variant="standard"
          defaultValue={new Date()}
          onChange={filterDateFrom}                                            
          label="Start Execution *" color="primary"
          InputLabelProps={{
           shrink: true                                              
           }}
          />
```

Can you point me to the right solution?
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to set a default date for a Material-ui TextField Type=date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54714316/how-to-set-a-default-date-for-a-material-ui-textfield-type-date)

Comment: Unfortunately not. It is working only if I set the default with a string. It seems like the new Date() function is not working

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<TextField 
      id="dateTimeFrom"                                        
      type="date"
      variant="standard"
      defaultValue={new Date().getDay()+"-"+(new Date().getMonth()+1)+"-"+new Date().getFullYear()}
      onChange={filterDateFrom}                                            
      label="Start Execution *" color="primary"
      InputLabelProps={{
       shrink: true                                              
       }}
      />
```

Comment: I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49277112/react-js-how-to-set-a-default-value-for-input-date-type . The problem is that then the date filter is not working. I edited my post with a screenshot

Comment: No getting your problem.Please elaborate

Comment: thanks to the post that I have linked, I managed to set defaults for my date picker. The problem is now that when I do a web service call with the date converted in the ISOString (as the post suggests), my service call is not working. I think it is due to the new date format.